# Windows command line copy based on binary file comparison

Tags: robocopy

I'm looking for a utility, built-in or not, that can let me essentially perform a robocopy-like operation but with a binary file comparison instead of date comparison.

Essentially, I have a git hook which checks out the most recent version of the repo and then runs robocopy to copy the files that have changed to a particular location. For whatever reason, it deems all files to have changed, presumably because the checkout process is touching their date stamps. I need a way to perform this action with binary file checking. Speed is not a priority, I just need it to be accurate and not overwrite the entire remote folder every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I ended up using BeyondCompare, which is a paid product we happened to have a license for.

```
BComp.com @"X:\Path\To\bc.cfg" /silent
```

Where bc.cfg is

```
log verbose "X:\path\to\log\bclog.txt"
criteria crc
load "X:\source\path" "X:\dest\path"
sync update:left->right
```

To do the equivalent of robocopy's /mir the last line could also be:

```
sync mirror:left->right
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a copy script and use the output of FC command as your input condition.
FC file1.tmp file2.tmp
If the result is 'no difference encountered', then put condition to skip, otherwise to copy.

Comment: Thanks, i'm really looking for something I don't have to write any more logic around as this is already hacked together pretty sketchily. The less parsing through command output to decide what to copy the better.

Comment: An alternate to this but similar, would be to use FC on all files needed and output that into a text file and then read the necessary info from there. That will also provide you with an equivalent to a log and would make tracing eventual problems easier. As FC would actually need a list to work with, that you can obtain by a dir command and duplicate it with excel columns (for the purpose of using it with FC).